# SwiftUI: how to use .overlay with GeometryReader in this instance?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, geometryreader

I know that it's common to use `.background` or `.overlay` to wrap a `GeometryReader` so that it doesn't modify parent views, but in this instance I don't have any views in the `VStack` to attach `.background` or `.overlay` to.  I tried using an `EmptyView` then using `.overlay` but my view disappeared.

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in  //how can I wrap this in a .overlay so it doesn't manipulate parent views?
                SecondView(proxy: geometry)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Color.clear` - it won't make your view disappear and will keep the layout.

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            /// here!
            Color.clear.overlay(
                GeometryReader { geometry in  //how can I wrap this in a .overlay so it doesn't manipulate parent views?
                    SecondView(proxy: geometry)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```